# Convert into different currencies by prefix

Tags: php

I am planning to convert a value into different currencies, depending on the chosen language.
The text is a description for something and it includes the following string:

"text description €€€59€€€ more description".

What I want to do is to extract the number between the €€€ signs, call a function with the 59 as parameter and replace €€€59€€€ by the actual converted value returned by the function.

I think this function will be very helpful already

```
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $str, $matches);
```

Then I can call my function with the matches. But how can I replace it on the correct place?

Thanks

Comment: [`preg_replace_callback`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$text = "text description €€€59€€€ more description";
function currency($matches)
{
    return "_new_val_";
}
echo $text . "\n";
echo preg_replace_callback('!\d+!', "currency", $text);
```

**Output:**

```
text description €€€59€€€ more description
text description €€€_new_val_€€€ more description
```

Comment: perfect. and then just a str_replace to remove the €€€ signs... thank you!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.

Comment: I am struggling with the following line: $text = "text description ###59.99### more description"; How will this be working with a float or int? It is possible that the number will be a float or an int. And also it should only call this function if the number in within the "###" signs. Now it is replacing all numbers in the text.

Comment: echo preg_replace_callback('!#{3}\d+.?\d+#{3}!', "currency", $text); Did the magic :)